# ElasticSearch filter on exact url

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I create this document in my index:

```
put /nursery/rhyme/1
{
  "url" : "http://example.com/mary",
  "text" : "Mary had a little lamb"
}
```

Why does this query not return anything?

```
POST /nursery/rhyme/_search
{
   "query" :  {
     "match_all" : {}
   },
   "filter" : {
     "term" : {
       "url" : "http://example.com/mary"
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the mapping of url in your index? `GET /nursery/rhyme/_mappping`. Seems to be `analyzed`.

Comment: {
  "nursery": {
    "mappings": {
      "rhyme": {
        "properties": {
          "text": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "url": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: I got it right. url is `analyzed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) finds documents that contain the exact term specified in the inverted index. When you save the document, the url property is `analyzed` and it will result in the following terms (with the default analyzer) : [http, example, com, mary].

So what you currently have in you inverted index is that bunch of terms, non of them is `http://example.com/mary`.

What you want is to [not analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#custom-field-mappings) the url property or to do a [Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) that will split the query into terms just like when indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Exact Match does not work for `analyzed` field. A string is by default `analyzed` which means `http://example.com/mary` string will be split and stored in `reverse index` as `http` , `example` , `com` , `mary`. That's why your query results  in no output.

You can make your field `not analyzed`

```
{
"url": {
    "type":     "string",
    "index":    "not_analyzed"
  } 
 }
```

but for this you will have to reindex your index.

Study about [not_analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html) and [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) here.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In the ElasticSearch **7.x** you have to use type "keyword" in maping properties, which is not analized https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html